# Is this object copied or is its reference carried over into this closure? (Objective-C block in a GCD queue)

Tags: objective-c, closures, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I'm relatively new to Objective-C and iOS programming (only more seriously programming in this environment recently). As such, I'm trying to get a better handle of the ins and outs.

So, that said, I have this bit of code below where I take the contents of a view and encode those contents as a Base64 string.  As you can see, I create a copy of those bits since, while this block is doing its work, it's likely that the layer will see changes. This is my attempt to avoid any conflicts.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateCopy((__bridge CGImageRef)self.interactiveLayer.layer.contents);

dispatch_async(self.mySerialWorkerQueue, ^{
    @autoreleasepool {

        if (imageRef) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
            CGImageRelease(imageRef);

            NSData *contentsData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            NSString *encodedContents = [contentsData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
            ...
```

So the question is, is `CGImageCreateCopy` redundant? If I simply did the following:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = (__bridge CGImageRef)self.interactiveLayer.layer.contents;
```

...does the closure hang onto a reference to that data, or does it create a local copy of the underlying data?

As a side note, if anyone has suggestions for improving the work itself (such as directly Base64-encoding a CGImage instead), I would be immensely grateful!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block will copy the value of any (non-`__block`) variables that it captures, when the block is created. When the block is copied, it will 1) retain any captured variables of object pointer type, and 2) for captured variables of block pointer type, it will furthermore copy it.

`CGImageRef` is not an Objective-C object pointer type, so nothing memory-management-wise will be done with it. The value of the variable (`imageRef`, a pointer to CGImage structure) is copied (`=`) when the block is created. That's it. If you want to make sure the CGImage object remains alive when the block executes, you need to retain it somehow and release it when no longer needed.

One way you could do that would be to do a `CFRetain` (or `CGImageRetain`) on it; and then do `CFRelease` (or `CGImageRelease`) when the block is done with it. The problem is there's no good way to detect when the block is "done with it". You could put the release inside the block at the end, which will work in this case since we know that `dispatch_async` will execute the block exactly once. But this is bad in general because you are releasing something in a different scope than you retained it; if the block is not run at all, then it will be a leak; if the block is run more than once, it will be over-release.

Another way to make the block keep the CGImage object is to cast the `CGImageRef` into an Objective-C object pointer type (e.g. `id`), and then have the block capture that. That way, the block will retain it when the block is copied, and release it when the block is deallocated, just like with normal Objective-C object pointers.

"Copying" is different from retaining. As to whether you need `CGImageCreateCopy`; that depends on whether you need a separate copy or not.

Comment: RE: "Copying is different from retaining." Right. In this case I do need a copy. I didn't know about the `__block` attribute. That's a good one to know. I also like the idea of casting to `id` instead of dealing with an extra retain and release. That will serve me well in some other places. Thanks for the thorough answer. It's good to have my deductions confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it just occurred to me that I can test this (duh), and what I observed is that the memory address remains the same once inside the block.  So it does indeed appear that the reference to the same location in memory is what is being carried over (makes sense). So it looks like  `CGImageCreateCopy` is the way to go in my case here.

I'll leave this up in case it may prove helpful to someone but any confirmation of this would be great.